# Intellij IDEA long processing for grails app with warning "too much output to process"

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, jvm

I new to Intellij for Grails app while run the app it execute lot of thing with the warning "Too much output to process" & takes comparatively more time to start the server.
Below is the log screen

```
(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:687)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener.initWebApplicationContext(GrailsContextLoaderListener.java:71)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4992)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5490)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not copy a non-root Method
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.copy(Method.java:151)
    ... 57 more
Jun 20, 2015 11:53:02 PM org.springsource.loaded.jvm.JVM copyMethod
SEVERE: Problems copying method. Incompatible JVM?
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor56.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springsource.loaded.jvm.JVM.copyMethod(JVM.java:134)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.OriginalClassInvoker.createJavaMethod(OriginalClassInvoker.java:68)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlClassGetMethods(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:168)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.getMethodIfAvailable(ClassUtils.java:672)
    at org.springframework.beans.GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor.<init>(GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor.java:72)
    at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.buildGenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:353)
    at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.<init>(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:307)
    at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.forClass(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.getPropertyDescriptors(BeanUtils.java:360)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ClassPropertyFetcher.init(ClassPropertyFetcher.java:193)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ClassPropertyFetcher.<init>(ClassPropertyFetcher.java:91)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ClassPropertyFetcher.forClass(ClassPropertyFetcher.java:82)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ClassPropertyFetcher.forClass(ClassPropertyFetcher.java:63)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.AbstractGrailsClass.<init>(AbstractGrailsClass.java:84)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsBootstrapClass.<init>(DefaultGrailsBootstrapClass.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrConstructorNewInstance(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1002)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ArtefactHandlerAdapter.newArtefactClass(ArtefactHandlerAdapter.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsApplication.addArtefact(DefaultGrailsApplication.java:775)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsApplication.addArtefact(DefaultGrailsApplication.java:477)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsApplication.configureLoadedClasses(DefaultGrailsApplication.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsApplication.initialise(DefaultGrailsApplication.java:682)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.project.plugins.GrailsProjectPluginLoader$_loadPlugins_closure2.doCall(GrailsProjectPluginLoader.groovy:132)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.project.plugins.GrailsProjectPluginLoader$_loadPlugins_closure2.call(GrailsProjectPluginLoader.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.api.BaseSettingsApi.profile(BaseSettingsApi.java:342)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.project.plugins.GrailsProjectPluginLoader.loadPlugins(GrailsProjectPluginLoader.groovy:99)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.GrailsPluginManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(GrailsPluginManagerFactoryBean.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1613)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1550)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:687)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener.initWebApplicationContext(GrailsContextLoaderListener.java:71)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4992)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5490)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not copy a non-root Method
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.copy(Method.java:151)
    ... 57 more
Jun 20, 2015 11:53:02 PM org.springsource.loaded.jvm.JVM copyMethod
SEVERE: Problems copying method. Incompatible JVM?
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor56.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springsource.loaded.jvm.JVM.copyMethod(JVM.java:134)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.OriginalClassInvoker.createJavaMethod(OriginalClassInvoker.java:68)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlClassGetMethods(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:168)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.getMethodIfAvailable(ClassUtils.java:672)
    at org.springframework.beans.GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor.<init>(GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor.java:72)
    at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.buildGenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:353)
    at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.<init>(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:307)
    at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.forClass(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.getPropertyDescriptors(BeanUtils.java:360)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ClassPropertyFetcher.init(ClassPropertyFetcher.java:193)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ClassPropertyFetcher.<init>(ClassPropertyFetcher.java:91)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ClassPropertyFetcher.forClass(ClassPropertyFetcher.java:82)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ClassPropertyFetcher.forClass(ClassPropertyFetcher.java:63)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.AbstractGrailsClass.<init>(AbstractGrailsClass.java:84)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsBootstrapClass.<init>(DefaultGrailsBootstrapClass.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrConstructorNewInstance(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1002)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ArtefactHandlerAdapter.newArtefactClass(ArtefactHandlerAdapter.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsApplication.addArtefact(DefaultGrailsApplication.java:775)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsApplication.addArtefact(DefaultGrailsApplication.java:477)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsApplication.configureLoadedClasses(DefaultGrailsApplication.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsApplication.initialise(DefaultGrailsApplication.java:682)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.project.plugins.GrailsProjectPluginLoader$_loadPlugins_closure2.doCall(GrailsProjectPluginLoader.groovy:132)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.project.plugins.GrailsProjectPluginLoader$_loadPlugins_closure2.call(GrailsProjectPluginLoader.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.api.BaseSettingsApi.profile(BaseSettingsApi.java:342)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.project.plugins.GrailsProjectPluginLoader.loadPlugins(GrailsProjectPluginLoader.groovy:99)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.GrailsPluginManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(GrailsPluginManagerFactoryBean.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1613)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1550)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:687)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener.initWebApplicationContext(GrailsContextLoaderListener.java:71)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4992)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5490)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not copy a non-root Method
```

Any possible solution for this?

Comment: Check the JVM configuration, are you sure you have a compatible JVM?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is the problem of using a wrong JDK for your project. And it mainly arises incompatible version like the latest versions namely `1.8.45` etc. Can you please try with some older JDK like `1.8.25` and let us know if it works?

I earlier had such an issue and changing the JDK to `1.8.25` for `Grails 2.4.4`solved my problem.

Please try and it should work.